# Make flutter Datepicker rounded at edges

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to achieve flutter DatePicker rounded corner without installing any external packages ,
I tried to make a new custom datepicker and change some of borders in it but don't work . Any suggestion will be great

Comment: Please post your code. It's hard to say without knowing what you've already tried.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if you still need an answer but you can use the `dialogTheme` of `showDatePicker`:

```dart
await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: currentDate,
      initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
      firstDate:
          DateTime(currentDate.day, currentDate.month, currentDate.year - 100),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, child) {
        return Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            dialogTheme: DialogTheme(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0), // this is the border radius of the picker
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );
```